# Docker desktop - kubernetes failed to start

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I have installed Docker Desktop (`version : 2.3.0.4`) and enabled `Kubernetes`.
I deployed couple of PODS and everything was working fine, Since yesterday I am facing a weird issue mentioned below:

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connectex: No 
connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

As such, no changes were made on my system. I am using Linux Containers on Windows 10 machine.

Following steps I have tried:

1. Restarted the Docker Desktop
2. Tried the same with minikube and Docker Desktop both
3. Tried to disable the firewall but due to some permissions, I am not able to turn it off.
4. I have reset the kubernetes cluster as well.

[image: Docker Desktop Error]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally,I found the solution for this.

VPN was causing the issue, I am using my office laptop and after restart, VPN was enabled and logged-in and due to this Kubernetes was not working.

After disabling the VPN, Kubernetes cluster working fine.

[image: pods]

Hope that helps others as well.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Kubernetes should work even within an office/proxied environment. What part of Kubernetes is being affected by the VPN? Which part of the VPN is blocking Kubernetes from starting?

Comment: In my case, Kubernetes starts failed due to connection issue to kubernetes site in China.

Comment: I have a work proxy that seemed to mess with my k8s. I tried purging data, resetting and restarting everything but nothing worked. The option that enabled it for me was Settings (the gear icon) -> Resources -> Enable Manual proxy configuration -> add `*` to Bypass proxy settings for these hosts & domains.

Answer (score 163):

I tried numerous changes to fix docker desktop Kubernetes failing to start. What finally worked:

Clicked the **troubleshooting icon** (it's a **bug icon** at the top right corner) and then chose **Clean/Purge Data**.*

Comment: I can confirm that using *Clean/Purge Data* directly without doing the above steps worked wonders (at least for me).

Comment: Clean/purge data + restart whole laptop is work for me.

Comment: I have tried just everything, almost bought a new laptop. only this solved the issue. Seen stackoverflow questions with 300+ thumbs up to the answers and none of them worked. Only this solved the issue. This answer must be in top 3 answers of stackoverflow all times.

Comment: Had to do this TWICE. But it worked without a system restart. I don't understand why I needed to do it twice. But I understand why this would work. So I will still give this a +1.

Comment: @GaidinD while kubernetes is running and resources are deployed, some of those resources may launch others if they go missing. Running it twice probably got rid of something that was launched while the purge was happening. It's an unlikely scenario that can be exacerbated by a slow host machine.

Comment: You don't need to restart the whole PC, just clean data / restart docker

Comment: after clicking purge data a dialog box showing with three options for which data to clear? `hyper-v` `wsl2` and `windows containers`

Comment: That must be new. My guess is that it previously cleared all 3 and now you have the option. Try hyper-v and let us know if that fixes it.

Comment: This didn't work for me either. What I found to work was changing `~/.kube/config` `current-context` to a context that existed in the `~/.kube/config` file (I had used `KUBECONFIG` variable to add a second config file and a context not in `~/.kube/config` – Docker didn't like that).

Comment: for some reason i had kubectx different-env to make it work

Comment: After Clean/Purge data worked !

Comment: This did work for me. In case this is helpful: I was already using Docker Desktop and Compose, and then enabled Kubernetes, and that's where it failed. I then did `Clean / Purge data` for Hyper-V and WSL 2, and that 1) got rid of all of my containers and images; and 2) fixed Kubernetes.

Once Kubernetes was working, I was able to re-deploy my Docker Compose project without Kubernetes.

Comment: I purged all three selections and when it was done problem completely went away. Thanks @N-ate

Answer (score 17):

I tried clean/purge data and resetting factory settings but that didn't worked.

I had to reset kubernetes cluster from here.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

For me, just "Clean and Purge" wasn't enough. Here is what I did.

1. Log off VPN
2. Go to bug and "Clean and Purge Data"
3. Also choose "Reset to Factory Defaults"
4. Restart Docker Desktop
5. Choose "Enable Kubernetes"

At this point, the "Starting" took a while for Kubernetes to be enabled. Now's it all good.

```
$ kubectl get namespace
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   80s
kube-node-lease   Active   82s
kube-public       Active   82s
kube-system       Active   82s
```

Answer (score 8):

My steps:

1. restart docker - it didn't help.
2. reset Kubernetes - it didn't help.
3. Adding missing 'wslconfig' file to C:\Users[MY USER] - it didn't help.
4. Restart the computer between any step - it didn't help.
5. stop using Wsl reuse Wsl - it didn't help.
6. uninstall docker and install again and enable Kubernetes - it didn't help.
7. Remove '.kube' folder from C:\Users[MY USER] and reset Kubernetes - It causes the Kubernetes to try stopping, and after failure - restart docker - which succeeded.

Comment: #7 is important. If you keep your kube configs read only, docker desktop will not start Kubernetes for the first time. You must allow writes to your kube configs for docker desktop to start Kubernetes. Otherwise it is stuck in "Starting" perpetually with no real answer.

Comment: #7th step saved me. It's worked!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the corporate proxy server caused the Kubernetes startup to fail. Addiing *.docker.internal to the no_proxy hosts solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

My docker-desktop is running behind the company proxy server.
I deleted following Proxy Env Variables from my windows OS.

```
HTTPS_PROXY:serveraddess
HTTP_PROXY:serveraddress
```

and I set up manual proxy in docker desktop.
[image]

Comment: Similar issue for me. I had to add `*` to the "Bypass proxy settings for these hosts & domains" field.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.

- Install Minikube

I install minikube and I run as following on windows 10.
[starting of kubectl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRkRg.png)
Then I gave permission for docker.

- Check cluster-info

When I check cluster-info result as following
[cluster info results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URIW3.png)

- Try to get pods

When I try to get pods I did not get any error.

Comment: Minikube is a whole different story.

Answer (score 0):

As @N-ate mentioned above, after clicking Clean/Purge Data which removes all downloaded images from my computer, now docker and kubernates are running properly.
As you can see in the image below, I only have kubernates images running on docker and it takes most of the allocated memory. I guess  the failure of starting kubernates was related to this memory issue.
[image: docker and kuber running image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Kubernetes (Docker Desktop on Mac) is not running properly though I can manage Pods, Services, etc., when I opened the Docker Desktop, it says

> Kubernetes failed to start (red background)

I managed to fix the issue by resetting Docker Desktop and Prune/cleaning the storage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for others but for some reasons, the above suggested options didn't work for me while fixing K8s on Docker Desktop on Windows. Tried fixing by *cleaning the cluster, resetting to default, restarting pc, installing previous versions of Docker Desktop, enabling my pc HiperVisor, and giving it more resource priority, and others* but yet still K8s failed to start, even though the Docker starts.

I chanced on **Minikube** as an alternative tool (without UI) to create my cluster and interacted with it using **Kubectl**.

And K8s worked for me locally.

[image]

I followed this guide - https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable/Stop any VPN
2. From Docker Desktop Press Reset Kubernetes Cluster.

**Note: #2 will remove any stack and data.**

[image]

The above action will result this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a working Kubernetes (k8s) cluster with Docker v4.20. However, after installing a series of Windows updates and updating Docker Desktop to v4.22, both Kubernetes and the Docker engine failed to start. I had to reinstall Docker Desktop to get the Docker engine running again. Unfortunately, neither the factory reset nor the "Clean/Purge data" options helped with Kubernetes. However, using the "Reset Kubernetes cluster" option resolved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Even I had similar problem after updating to Docker desktop(version 4.11.1). After I downgraded the version it works fine.

**Troubleshooting steps**

check is there any errors by running following command

**kubectl get events|grep node**

and make sure all pods are in running state.

**kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system**